# AS3 workers and large data files not possible?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

so I load large amounts of data from services.  I just updated our project to the latest 4.7 FB with Flex 4.9 SDK and AIR 3.4.  Implemented workers.  They seem to work great for one-off tasks EXCEPT when it comes to internet data loading.  I haven't found the magic limit yet, but it seems as though if you load an internet request (Loader, URLLoader, HttpService... whatever) that is receiving a large replay, the worker just locks up and quits.  The main thread can do this just fine in all cases (but with UI being unresponsive until the load is done).  This is why I was so excited about workers is to offload the sometimes large data loads to the background workers.

Has anyone else run into this?  I saw comments on the Worker class docs online where a few other people have seen similar problems and suggest putting data loading from the internet back on the main thread.  Seems like "what's the point of a worker then"?

Can they only do local calculations?  Math is cool... but HTTP Gets are not?

I tried giving the worker app privileges.. no help there.  Is there a magic worker.canloadlargefiles = true?  (rhetorical).

Any direction or help here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is not for mobile platforms, is it?

Comment: Internet requests spawns their own separate thread. So you do not need to worry about putting it on the "main" thread, because it's all async.

Comment: @gladoscc I understand the async mechanisms that are in play, the main issue comes in parsing the response when it is sooo large. you can have the main thread manage the GETs (async) and then hand the response to a worker for processing, but my point is ... why do I have to?  Why can't the worker both fetch and process the data?  Why does the main thread fetch GETs fine, but a worker hangs on the same request??

Comment: Maybe there's a memory limit for workers?  Since URLRequest is already threaded, the memory consumption for copying over the request is probably what's causing an error, I'm assuming any exceptions that happen in the child thread will cause it to just exit and close.  Does this happen when you create a new thread to JUST process?

Comment: no it doesn't.  That's why I said the same thing and asked this question... is there a memory limit to them? There is VERY limited docs yet about workers so I was hoping someone knew a definitive answer to why this occurs.

Comment: Create a new worker AFTER you get the GET request. Workers

Comment: @gladoscc that is what I am doing now... again I just don't see why a worker can't do it.  It will be interesting to see what other limits workers have I guess.  Per what docs I've found, it should be just a separate vm running a separate swf, so in theory it should be able to do what the main can do... but alas... this apparently not the case.  Thanks for the input guys...

Comment: I don't have an answer, but have you tried with 3.5? If that does the same, might be worth posting it on their JIRA http://bugs.adobe.com/flashplayer/

Comment: @JasonReeves sorry to hijack here, do you still have your DataConnectivityCS3.mxp file uploaded? i cant access the url anymore - http://www.jasondev.com/DataConnectivityCS3.mxp

Comment: @whitedeath sorry no.  I moved the domain and haven't maintained a site there in quite some time.  I'll check to see if I can find the file for you... but that was a long time ago.

Comment: @JasonReeves no worries jason thanks allot but never mind found a workaround. thanks anyways man

Answer (score 0):

Well not a solution, but a **workaround**. Instead of digging internals of VM, use KISS (Keep It Simple and Stupid) principle, divide your data into managable chunks. You do not need to divide the files or data but can tell the server do it by a request format so it sends you manageable portions of data that will not timeout the VM. Retrieve and join the chunks on the client side to form the big file back.

Thats my two cents.